# What's the difference between "kind of" and "a little bit"?

Tags: meaning, differences

I am a little bit angry.
I am kind of angry.

I searched the two phrases, but can't found the difference.
Are them the same?

Comment: Both phrases are often defined with the same definition: "to some extent". There might be very mild differences in their connotation, but it probably isn't worth thinking about if you're learning English. Hell, most English speakers themselves probably wouldn't be able to describe their differences.

Comment: They're two different metaphors. _A little bit angry_ refers to the **amount** of emotion -- small, not large. _Kind of angry_ refers to the **type of emotion** -- more anger than (e.g.) amusement, approval, or disinterest.

Comment: What @JohnLawler said! Quantity of anger vs quality of angriness.

Answer (score 3):

*Kind of* is an informal phrase which means *to some extent*.  In that sense, it means the same as "little bit."

"Kind of" may also imply some vagueness, which may indicate the emotion being felt is not pure anger or there is some uncertainty about the anger being felt, although, from the example, it's probably being used to mean "a little bit."

The term "sort of" is also often used, interchangeably with "kind of" and "a little bit"--more colloquial forms might be "kinda," "sorta," and "a little."

Comment: *Kind of* can mean *to some extent*. But it can also mean **a** *kind of*, and that's also the main meaning for *sort of* -- kind, sort, type. In the latter case they refer to a type of something more than they do to a degree of something.